# Create different projects on a repositiry and Control each one individually

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a repository on gitlab and a wanted to create independent sub directories to my project, for instance:

- MyProjectWeb
- MyProjectForms
- MyProjectConsole
- Robots

  - Robot_Mailling
  - Robot_Survey
  - Robot_Finance

I want to elevate this sub directories to a "repository" state, because I want to create independent git control to each one.

Is this the right way? Do I have to do something different?

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- create one repository on GitLab per independent project/folder
- reference each repository in your main existing GitLab repository, as [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

In a clone of your main project, you would use [`git submodule add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-add-bltbranchgt-f--force--nameltnamegt--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--ltrepositorygtltpathgt) in order to add the other repository

```
cd /path/to/main/pre
git submodule add MyProjectWeb https://gitlab.com/<me>/MyProjectWeb
git commit -m "Add MyProjectWeb as submodule"
git push
```